# Can someone check my code to see why this message pops up "Error: could not find function "N1""

Tags: r, rep

I know its a simple fix but can someone please take a look at it:

```
a12= 0
a21= 0
K1= 1000
K2= 600
r1= 0.2
r2= 0.1
N1= ((K1 - a12*K2)/(1 - a12*a21))
N2= ((K2 - a21*K1)/(1 - a21*a12))
for(t in 1:80){
  N1[t+1]= N1(t) + r1*N1(t)*(K1 - N1 - a12*N2)/K1
  N2[t+1]= N2(t) + r2*N2(t)*(K2 - N2 - a21*N1)/K2
}
## Error: could not find function "N1"
```

Corrected Code:

```
N1= rep(0,80)
N2= rep(0,80)
a12= 0
a21= 0
K1= 1000
K2= 600
r1= 0.2
r2= 0.1
N1[1]= ((K1 - a12*K2)/(1 - a12*a21))
N2[1]= ((K2 - a21*K1)/(1 - a21*a12))
for(t in 1:80){
N1[t+1]= N1[t] + r1*N1[t]*(K1 - N1[t] - a12*N2[t])/K1
N2[t+1]= N2[t] + r2*N2[t]*(K2 - N2[t] - a21*N1[t])/K2
}
plot(1:81, N1, type="l", lwd=3, xlab="Time")
lines(1:81, N2, lwd=3, col='red')
```

When I ran my plots where I changed the values for a12 and a21 they looked like what I might expect since they modeled competitiveness between two species.

The three models I'm running:

```
no competition-        a12=0     a21=0
stable coexistence-    a12=0.25  a21=0.1
competitive exclusion- a12=0.25  a21=0.75
```

Comment: Because N1 is not defined as a function but just the value 1000.

Comment: When you post code please remove the `> and +` so it can be run without us removing those elements.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions of how to fix it. I'm trying to run a Lotka-Votera model and those are the formulas and those are the formulas I need to use for building my model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@e4e5f4 is correct in that your main problem is that you are using `(` round brackets were you need `[` square brackets.

However, in addition, you have an issue inside your `for` loop:

```
 # this is a problem, even with brackets corrected
 N1[t+1]= N1[t] + r1*N1[t]*(K1 - N1 - a12*N2)/K1
 N1[t+1]= N1[t] + r1*N1[t]*(K1 - N1 - a12*N2)/K1
                                 ^        ^
                          N1 & N2 are vectors
```

Since most mathematical operations in `R` are vectorized, the value being assigned (ie, the right hand side of your equation) is a vector whose length is growing at every iteration.

---

The subsequent warnings you are seeing come from trying to assign multiple values (ie a vector) into a single element of a vector.

You will see the same error if you try

```
 foo <- c(17, 23, 31)
 foo[3] <- 1:10
```

You are getting 158 of these warnings because you are iterating.

---

You most likely want to index those values (likely with `N1[[t]]` or `N1[[t-1]]`, etc)

Comment: I think I figured it out now. I added the N1 and N2 with N1=rep() and N2=rep(). And I relaced the old N1 and N2 with N[1] and N[2].

Answer (score 0):

Replace `N1(t)` with `N1[t]`. Do the same for `N2`.

Note: I think you are using `Matlab` syntax for array indexing which is different from `R` syntax.

Comment: I think received the equivalent to "over 9000" in R error messages when I did that cause I had too man to view any of them. But thanks for the help still.

Comment: did you replace both `N1()` and `N2()` to `N1[]` and `N2[]`

Comment: array indexing syntax is different in R and Matlab

Comment: When I change the N1() and N2() to N[] and N[] I receive over 50 warning messages. Alot of those are repeated (e.g. number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length)

Comment: that happens when you assign vector value `N1 + N1[t]` to scalar value `N1[t+1]`. If that is the intention of the code then ignore the warnings.